# Writting function that can operate on RDD and Seq in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, functional-programming, rdd

I am trying to write functions that can receive both Spark `RDD` and Scala native `Seq`, so that I can showcase the performance difference of the two approaches. However, I couldn't figure out a common type or interface for the aforesaid function parameters. Let's imagine something simple like computing the mean using a `map` operation. Both `RDD` and `Seq` have this operation. I've tried using the type `Either[RDD[Int], Seq[Int]]` but it just doesn't typecheck :/.

Any pointer would be very appreciated :)

Comment: You may try using a typeclass but the boilerplate would be too big, just duplicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. They don't show any common superclass - besides AnyRef I guess. Their `map` functions have completely different signature (params etc) even though they share a name (and purpose)

Comment: That's very sad, but there is nothing we can do :/ Thank you for your reply